# In JPA hibernate how to get data from both parent and child table without referencing foreign key?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using posgGreSQL DB. I am using JPA to generate DBs.

I have two tables:
1) parent_table with columns: mapping_id, pcol1, pcol2, pcol3
2) child_table with columns: mapping_id, ccol1, ccol2, ccol3

'mapping_id' is foreign key between parent and child table.
Relationship is one to one.

Just like using cascade = CascadeType.ALL when you delete any record in parent table automatically respective record from child table also gets deleted. The 'delete' method of org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository deletes not only parent table's record but also child table's record.

In a similar way, when you just query parent table can we get corresponding record from child table also?

My current method in repository class is as below:

```
 @Query("SELECT ptable, ctable FROM ParentTable as ptable, 
ChildTable as cTable " + "WHERE ptable.mappingId = ctable.mappingId " +
                "AND ptable.mappingId =:mappingId")


List<Object[]> findSearchProfileBodyByMappingId(@Param("mappingId") Long mappingId);
```

In above query, I am trying to get data from both parent and child table using foreign key where clause. I am trying to find out better way of expressing query.

Comment: Well if you don't want to refer foreign key then I would also get the same way as you are getting.

Comment: @MyTwoCents but in my above query I am actually referring to foreign key. In the example I have given 'mappingId' is foreign key.

Comment: let's say ParentTable has a field INT mapId and ChildTable has a field INT mapId
how will you join them p.mapId=c.mapId  This is what I meant with your above query

Comment: Yes got what you mean and same I am doing here. But I want to avoid this. You see when you delete you just give mapId and delete operation on record of parent table deletes related record from child table too.